# Apache directory with Shibboleth IDP

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, shibboleth, idp

How can we generate idp-metadata when using Apache Directory service with Shibboleth IDP? I am working on setting up an SSO environment on my local using Shibboleth SP, Shibboleth IDP, Apache Directory services. Currently when I try to access my application from the Apache server, I get the following error on the page : 
**opensaml::saml2md::MetadataException
opensaml::saml2md::MetadataException at (http://localhost:91/WebUI/)
Unable to locate metadata for identity provider (https://localhost:9443/idp/shibboleth)** 
Usually, in case of production scenario, we get the idp-metadata from client and just need to enter the location etc in shibboleth2.xml, but I am setting everything on my local, so need to know how to generate and use idp-meta data.

Thanks,
Ritesh

Comment: Can you show us your configuration files? apache and shibboleth. Why the ports are different in your both URL?

Comment: Shibboleth2.xml    
    <RequestMapper type="Native">  
        <RequestMap>  
            <Host name="localhost:8080">  
                <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>  
            </Host>  
        </RequestMap>  
    </RequestMapper>  

    <ApplicationDefaults entityID="http://localhost:8080/WebUI"  
                         REMOTE_USER="sn eppn persistent-id targeted-id" signing="false" encryption="false" attributePrefix="AJP_"  homeURL="http://localhost:8080/WebUI">

Comment: Apache24.config  
LoadModule mod_shib C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so
ShibCompatValidUser Off

<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
  Satisfy any
  Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /WebUI >
AuthType shibboleth
ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
require valid-user
</Location>

Comment: httpd.config

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so

Listen 91
ProxyIOBufferSize 65536
ProxyPass /WebUI ajp://localhost:8010/WebUI

Include C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/apache24.config

Comment: Where are the logic for ports - 91 and 9443?

Comment: httpd.config file is for Apache. So it listens to Port 91 using "Listen 91 " and in my Tomcat server.xml, I have :  <Connector port="9443" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
  keystoreFile="C:/opt/shibboleth-idp/credentials/idp.jks" keyAlias="localhost" keystorePass="changeit" />